# InsertionSort Algorithm, Whats Wrong with my Code?

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying out a InsertSort Algorithm for an input of strings stored in a vector.

What I do is to input some strings into the vector,
Then i use insertionsort to sort the vectors.

But I'm not sure why does it not work! Could anyone point me to the right direction?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    vector <string> names; //vector to store
    string input; //input is the variable of strings

    cout<<"Input a list of names \n";
    cout<<"To end the list type 'END'" <<endl;

    while (true){
        getline(cin, input);

        if (input =="END")
        break;

        names.push_back(input); //push into vector names
    }


  //my insertsort starts here
  string temp;
  int i;
  for (int j = 1; j < names.size(); j++){
        i = j - 1;        

        while ((i>0) && (names[i]>names[j]) ) {

            names[i+1] = names[i];

            i=i-1;         
                                                 }

        names[i+1] = names[j];

    }



    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<names.size (); i++)
    cout<<names[i]<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Thanks a bunch

EDIT:
I will be inputing strings for example I will type:

Peter
Apple
Rabbit

And my desired output is, in alphabatical order,:

Apple
Peter
Rabbit

At the moment with the example input, I get:
Peter
Apple
Rabbit

EDIT 3:

My insert sort now looks like this:

```
 string temp;
  int i;
  for (int j = 1; j < names.size(); j++){
        i = j - 1;        
        temp = names[j];

 while ((i>=0) && (names[i]>names[j]) ) {
    names[i+1] = names[i];
    i=i-1;                                                  
                                        }

 names[i+1] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: define "does not work". what input are you using and what output are you geting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed one point:

```
 //You have to remember names[j] before while loop
 //the variable temp is never used
 temp = names[j];
 while ((i>=0) && (names[i]>temp) ) {
    names[i+1] = names[i];
    i=i-1;                                                  
 }
 names[i+1] = temp;
 // since names[j] was already been filled by other words during swapping
```

If it is not required to use insertion sort, you'd better use stl sort algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code as you advised, but the output is still wrong, which I don't get either. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: @CandyMan i >0 should be i>=0 otherwise the first spot will not be examined. see my updated answer?

Comment: Pardon me, but I think the output is wrong for longer inputs. What's wrong with my algorithm?

Comment: Ah, what I meant was, when I entered more elements like, instead of Apple, Candy, Egg, I have, Apple, Candy, Egg, Butter, Peter.

Comment: Woops, I might not have been clear. Sorry bout that. I input the elements in separate lines, that is, after hitting enter in the console window, and not all in one line.

Comment: Here is the link: http://liveworkspace.org/code/4knfUg$1

I would type in one element, hit enter, then type in the next, and hit enter, and so on, ending it with "END" in the last input to stop it.

Comment: @CandyMan Sorry, I was careless, there is one more error in the code. the compare condition was not right, see my updated post and code here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1UGtPU$0